# angular data table export buttons not showing

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using [**angular-datatable**](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withButtons) plugin, with export buttons.I am using collection button to export data but the buttons are not showing rather the data table sorting and paging options become disabled when i am adding button options.Here is the [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Js7ZGQAbJMYQVX1NchN?p=preview)

```js
$scope.vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withOption('order', [0, 'asc'])
  .withButtons([

    {
      extend: 'collection',
      text: 'Export',
      buttons: [

        {
          extend: 'print',
          title: 'My lists'
        },




        {

          extend: 'pdfHtml5',
          title: 'My lists'

        }


      ]
    }

  ]);
```

Comment: still need an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the necessary js and css files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
```

and

```
<script src="/projectName/theme/vendors/angular-datatables/plugins/buttons/angular-datatables.buttons.min.js"></script>
```